# moment js `format` method breaks time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to create current date with time (7 am) with UTC timezone, but when I'm trying to format it time changing to wrong value:

code:

```js
var t_day = moment().utcOffset(0)
t_day.set({ hour: 7, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 })
console.log(t_day.toISOString())
console.log(t_day.format('MMM DD, YYYY HH:MM'))
```

Output:

```
2020-10-28T07:00:00.000Z
Oct 28, 2020 07:10
```

From where this 10 minutes came and how to format date properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mm` would refer to minutes:

```js
var t_day = moment().utcOffset(0)
t_day.set({ hour: 7, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 })
console.log(t_day.toISOString())
console.log(t_day.format('MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`MM` in the format reffers to the month,
what you're looking for is `mm`

```js
console.log(t_day.format('MMM DD, YYYY HH:MM')) // MM reffers to the month

// the correct should be:
console.log(t_day.format('MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm'))
```